# CSS Transform scale 'glitchy' on firefox

Tags: css, animation, firefox, scale

I am trying to animate a line that expands both ways from the centre using `transform:scale` but for some reason the line kind of "rewinds" slightly when it reaches the end, but only on the right side of the line. This only seems to happen on firefox, (both on mobile and desktop) but seems fine on chrome.

```
<div class="line"></div>
<style>
.line {
    height: 4px;
    width: 5px;
    background-color: #5d496a;
    margin: 0 50%;
    animation: line_animation 1s forwards ;
}
@keyframes line_animation {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1,1);
    }
    100%{
        transform: scale(22,1);
    }
  }
</style>
```

I am still learning animations so I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be very appreciated.

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GRA6EYT2GLSX

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was an issue with scale being greater than 1.

Fixed by changing `width: 5px;` to `width: 15%;` and changed

```
@keyframes line_animation {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1,1);
    }
    100%{
        transform: scale(22,1);
    }
  }
```

to

```
@keyframes line_animation {
    from {
        transform: scale(0.01,1);
    }
    to{
        transform: scale(1,1);
    }
  }
```